# scapy module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to run the following code but I get a error saying "no module named scapy". I have installed scapy using pip install scapy.

```
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan("192.168.0.14")
```

Comment: are you calling the same executable of python that has this module installed. if you do `python3 -m pip freeze | grep scapy` does anything come back?

Comment: Maybe you `pip install` but are using python3 ? Try pip+python2, or pip3+python3

Comment: @aws_apprentice I get back scapy==2.4.3

Comment: and how are you running these functions? `python3 my_script.py` or from an IDE

Comment: @Demi-Lune installing scapy using pip3 fixed the issue

Comment: Maybe you are using python2 instead python3 and you have installed the scapy module for python3. Try run with python3.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that often happens to people that are new to Scapy.

If you are still experiencing this error.
please consider trying: pip3 install scapy.all

Then: from scapy.all import scapy, ARP, Ether, srp, arping

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was, Moving your python file to directory where scapy is installed. I use pycharm and scapy is installed in venv/lib. Make directory there (venv) and continue making python files. it should find scapy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).